# rails generate - "Could not find generator"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am following the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. In section [6.3.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users.html#sec-an_encrypted_password), I am trying to generate a migration file to add a Password field to my user model. Here is the code that I run:

```
rails generate add_passsword_digest_to_users password_digest:string
```

but this throws the error: `Could not find generator add_passsword_digest_to_users.`

i have used the `rails generate` command before and it worked perfectly. I'm not sure why I am getting this problem now.

version: Rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
rails generate migration add_passsword_digest_to_users password_digest:string
```

You simply forgot `migration` which is the generator to use for the other arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I missed it even after checking like 5 times! Should I just delete this question since it is my very obvious mistake or let it be?

Comment: @AyrtonSenna no need to delete, someone else might come across the same error.

Comment: Yes, that someone would be me. Thanks! And...I don't think you can delete your questions?

Comment: I got here because I was writing `rails generate neo4j:migration ...` the `neo4j:` was not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to include migration in the command. You can simply do

```
rails generate migration add_passsword_digest_to_users password_digest:string
```