# "Could not find generator figaro:install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the "Learn Ruby On Rails" pdf book from learn-rails.com.

I'm at chapter 13, "Configure".  Where we are supposed to do the command: "rails generate figaro:install"

In chapter 12 we installed the figaro gem,: "We’ve already installed the figaro gem in the Gemfile and run bundle install."

When I run that command I get: "Could not find generator figaro:install."

I started searching for similar questions, and I did find this question here: [rails generate - "Could not find generator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737719/rails-generate-could-not-find-generator)
where they were recommended to include "migration" into the command as well.

I included it in my command and I got it to do something, but I don't think it's doing what it should be?

```
invoke  active_record
/Users/NormalUse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb:57:in `validate_file_name!': Illegal name for migration file: figaro:install (ActiveRecord::IllegalMigrationNameError)
(only lower case letters, numbers, and '_' allowed)
from /Users/NormalUse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb:10:in `create_migration_file'
```

Then about 20 more lines as well. I just didn't want to put it all here.

The author goes on to say:

"Using the rails generate command, the figaro gem generates a config/application.yml file and lists it in your .gitignore file. The .gitignore file prevents the config/application.yml file from being saved in the Git repository so your credentials are kept private."

When I go to my project directory, and look inside the "config" folder, I do have an "application" file, but it ends with ".rb" and not "yml". So obviously the command didn't do what it is supposed to do, right?

Does anyone have any ideas for me?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.2 with RVM on Mac OSX 10.7.5

Comment: Did you put `gem "figaro"` line into your project's `Gemfile` file and then run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes the line here: gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0' gem 'figaro' is what we used. Then I did do the bundle install.

Comment: You may need to restart the Terminal: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/issues/180

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you're learning (welcome to the Rails community btw!), let me explain what Figaro does & how to use (install) it:

---

**Figaro**

Figaro is a way to create [ENV variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) in both development & production. It's a [gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) which you have to install before invoking from the Rails cmd

Like other Ruby gems in Rails, you have to add it to your `Gemfile`, which lists all the plugins your app will use. According to [RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/figaro), you could list it in your Gemfile like this:

```
#Gemfile
gem "figaro", "~> 0.7.0"
```

After you've added this line to your Gemfile, you need to install it. To do this, you should run `bundle install` to run the bundler (installer)

Once you've done this, you need to run this command from cmd:

```
rails generate figaro:install
```

---

**Error**

Your errors seem to indicate you've got migration problems?

> Illegal name for migration file: figaro:install
>   (ActiveRecord::IllegalMigrationNameError)

I would guess you called this command:

```
rake db:migrate figaro:install
```

If this is the case, you should perform any migrations by running `rake db:migrate` and then `rails generate figaro:install`. This will run the commands separately, which should help them work

Comment: Thank you very much Rich! Great, helpful answer. According to the book, it says to add this to the Gemfile: "gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0' gem 'figaro'", which I did, then we ran bundle install, which seemed to work just fine.   The command I called was: "rails generate figaro:install". Should I go ahead and change the Gemfile to your suggestion instead? I'm still worried about putting in wrong commands, and messing things up.

Comment: Thanks again Rich, I went ahead and edited my Gemfile with your suggestion and I'm good to go!

Comment: The version noted above (0.7.0) seems to help. When I tried to install figaro without specifying a version, it installed 1.1.0 (discovered during gem uninstall later). Using the lower version drove this 'generator not found' error away. Thanks. ~ confused but grateful

Comment: Both version `1.0.0` and `1.1.1` are not working. These one works.

Answer (score 13):

If you do this tutorial nowadays instead of "rails generate figaro:install" run command "figaro:install" due to figaro 1.0.0 version https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Comment: Thanks a lot :) btw, it was actually "figaro install"

Answer (score 4):

Please try below one:

bundle exec figaro install

Thank you